# missing ) after argument list (line 1) in javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I keep getting a "missing ) after argument list" (on line 1) when debugging my javascript with firebug. I don't know what is wrong as it seems all parentheses are there.

The function is supposed to place an image that can be clicked to open a lightbox in the div with id "bigPic".

Here's the relevant code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addContent(divId,filePath,comment) {
document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = "<div align=\"center\"><a href="+filePath+" title="+comment+" rel=\"lightbox\"><img src="+filePath+" alt="+comment+" style=\"max-height:270px;max-width:410px;\"/></a></div><div id="+comment+" align=\"center\"  style=\"font-family:Verdana;margin-top:-13px;color:white;background-color:#07396B;\"><p>"+comment+"</p></div>&nbsp;";
}
</script>
...
<div width="420px" height="320px" id="bigPic" name="bigPic">
<img src="http://www.villa-gloria-katouna.com/Pool%20viewsmall.JPG" />
</div>
...
echo "<div align=\"center\" style=\"display:inline; overflow:hidden;\"><img src=\"pics/$file\" style=\"cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;\" alt=\"$file\" height=\"30px\" width=\"30px\" onclick=\"addContent('bigPic', $file, $comment);\"/></a></div>&nbsp;";
```

Comment: That code is fine. Your error is somewhere else. Show your full code.

Comment: @Xeon06 "Fine" is a very...subjective word.

Comment: @Zirak as in, there are no bugs in it. But I might have been wrong, Pointy caught something I hadn't noticed.

Comment: What's up with the echo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot quote characters around "$file" and "$comment" in the "onclick" handler code.

```
     ... onclick=\"addContent('bigPic', '$file', '$comment');\" ...
```

I don't know PHP so that may or may not be the way to get quotes in the "onclick" string, but they need to be there. Otherwise if the comment is "hello world" that'll expand to

```
     ... onclick="addContent('bigPic', whatever-$file-is, hello world)" ...
```

which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: echo "<div align=\"center\" style=\"display:inline; overflow:hidden;\"><img src=\"pics/" . $file . "\" style=\"cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;\" alt=\"" . $file . "\" height=\"30px\" width=\"30px\" onclick=\"addContent('bigPic', 'pics/" . $file . "', '" . $comment . "');\"/></a></div>&nbsp;";    did the trick, thx!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
onclick=\"addContent('bigPic', '$file', '$comment');\"
```

instead of

```
onclick=\"addContent('bigPic', $file, $comment);\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script code as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addContent(divId,filePath,comment) {
document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = "<div align=\"center\"><a href=\"" + filePath + "\" title=\"" + comment + "\" rel=\"lightbox\"><img src=\"" + filePath + "\" alt=\"" + comment + "\" style=\"max-height:270px;max-width:410px;\"/></a></div><div id=\"" + comment + "\" align=\"center\"  style=\"font-family:Verdana;margin-top:-13px;color:white;background-color:#07396B;\"><p>\"" + comment + "\"</p></div>&nbsp;";
}
</script>
```

Also change your echo to

```
echo "<div align=\"center\" style=\"display:inline; overflow:hidden;\"><img src=\"pics/" . $file . "\" style=\"cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;\" alt=\"" . $file . "\" height=\"30px\" width=\"30px\" onclick=\"addContent('bigPic', '" . $file . "', '" . $comment . "');\"/></a></div>&nbsp;";
```

Comment: this still gives me the same errors, I will post my full code

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes as wrapper of string istead double prevent to writing backslashes. This faciliate now and in the future:)

```
'<div align="center">'
```